# Maps autocomplete unexpectedly clears search input

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to run a simple autocomplete intent and get the selected address in my android app. However. the search field automatically gets cleared after entering certain text, for no reason. The same code works perfectly fine elsewhere in the app. Here is a screen recording: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oP92sgY5u9Vco3Khky_E2OEmaA3OB8FB/view?usp=sharing

The activity:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.Autocomplete;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.model.AutocompleteActivityMode;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class GetDonorAddressActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText locField, hnbnField, streetField, pincodeField;
    private TextInputLayout hnbnTIL, streetTIL, pincodeTIL;
    private Button confirmDonation;
    private SharedPreferences userPref;
//    private TextWatcher clearErr;
    private static final int AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 108;

    private FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseStorage mFirebaseStorage;
    private StorageReference bookPhotosStorageReference;

    private String docId, userId;
    private double book_lat,book_lng;

    private static String TAG = "GETDONORADDRESS";
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 103;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_donor_address);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Set pickup address");

        docId = getIntent().getStringExtra("DON_DOC_ID");

        locField = findViewById(R.id.locField2_d);
        hnbnField = findViewById(R.id.hnbnET);
        streetField = findViewById(R.id.streetNameET);
        pincodeField = findViewById(R.id.pincodeET);

        hnbnTIL = findViewById(R.id.hnbnTIL);
        streetTIL = findViewById(R.id.streetNameTIL);
        pincodeTIL = findViewById(R.id.pincodeTIL);

        confirmDonation = findViewById(R.id.confirmDonationBtn);

        userPref = this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.UserPref),0);

        initFirebase();

        hnbnField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                hnbnTIL.setError(null);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        streetField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                streetTIL.setError(null);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        pincodeField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                pincodeTIL.setError(null);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        confirmDonation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder cBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GetDonorAddressActivity.this); // TODO: change to create bundle
                cBuilder.setTitle("Confirm donation");
                cBuilder.setMessage("By clicking confirm, you agree that the details you provided will be shared with a representative of the Foundation and you may be contacted for pickup-related issues.");
                cBuilder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        String mapsLoc = locField.getText().toString().trim();
                        String hnbn = hnbnField.getText().toString().trim();
                        String street = streetField.getText().toString().trim();
                        String pinCode = pincodeField.getText().toString().trim();

                        if (mapsLoc.isEmpty()) {
                            Toast.makeText(GetDonorAddressActivity.this, "Couldn't get your location. Please search for it manually.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        if (hnbn.isEmpty()) {
                            hnbnTIL.setError("Please fill in this field");
                        }

                        if (street.isEmpty()) {
                            streetTIL.setError("Please fill in this field");
                        }

                        if (pinCode.isEmpty()) {
                            pincodeTIL.setError("Please fill in this field");
                        }
                        final ProgressDialog sProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
                        sProgressDialog.setMessage("Just a moment...");
                        sProgressDialog.setTitle("Submitting");
                        sProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                        sProgressDialog.show();
                        String pickupAddress = "Maps address: " + mapsLoc + ",\n";
                        pickupAddress = pickupAddress + "House number and building name:" + hnbn + ",\n";

/*                        if (!streetField.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                            pickupAddress = pickupAddress + "Street name and other details: " + streetField.getText().toString().trim();
                        }*/

                        pickupAddress = pickupAddress + "Street name and other details: " + street;
                        pickupAddress = pickupAddress + "Pincode: " + pinCode;


                        DocumentReference donReference = mFirestore.collection("donations").document(docId);
                        donReference.update("lat", book_lat,"lng", book_lng, "address", pickupAddress, "status",1)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(GetDonorAddressActivity.this, MyDonationsActivity.class));
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                sProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to submit request. Please try again after some time.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                cBuilder.show();
            }
        });

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        populateUserLocation();

        findViewById(R.id.btn_search_listing_d).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onSearchCalled();
            }
        });

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

    }


    private void initFirebase() {
        try {
            mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();
            mFirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            bookPhotosStorageReference = mFirebaseStorage.getReference().child("book_photos");

            if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
                Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.places_api_key));
            }
//            PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "initFireBase: getCurrentUser error", e);
        }
    }

    private void populateUserLocation() {
        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

        book_lat = userPref.getFloat(getString(R.string.p_lat),0.0f);
        book_lng = userPref.getFloat(getString(R.string.p_lng),0.0f);

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(book_lat, book_lng, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
//        String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
//        String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
//        String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
//        String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
//        String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL
        locField.setText(address);
    }

    public void onSearchCalled() {
        // Set the fields to specify which types of place data to return.
        List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS, Place.Field.LAT_LNG);
        // Start the autocomplete intent.
        Intent mapsAC = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
                AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fields).setCountry("IN") //NIGERIA
                .build(this);
        startActivityForResult(mapsAC, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GetDonorAddressActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Discard your donation request?");
        builder.setMessage("You have unsaved changes. Would you like to stay or discard them?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Stay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
//                            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(UserProfileActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
//                            homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//                            homeIntent.putExtra("SNACKBAR_MSG", "Your profile has been saved");
//                            startActivity(homeIntent);

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Exit without saving", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                deleteDoc();
                Intent homeActivity = new Intent(GetDonorAddressActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(homeActivity);
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }


    private void deleteDoc() {
        String picUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("PIC_URL");
        Toast.makeText(this, picUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(picUrl);
        storageReference.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.d("firebasestorage", "onSuccess: deleted photo");
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Log.e("firebasestorage", "onFailure: did not delete photo");
            }
        });

        final ProgressDialog cProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        cProgressDialog.setTitle("Removing...");
        cProgressDialog.setMessage("Cancelling your donation request, just a moment");
        cProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        cProgressDialog.show();
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        db.collection("donations").document(docId)
                .delete()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        cProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully deleted!");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        cProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error deleting document", e);
                    }
                });

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

//        autofillBoardTemp();

        switch (requestCode) {
            case AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE: // for places search
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "RESULT_OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(imageReturnedIntent);
                    //Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId() + ", " + place.getAddress());
                    //Toast.makeText(CreateListingActivity.this, "ID: " + place.getId() + "address:" + place.getAddress() + "Name:" + place.getName() + " latlong: " + place.getLatLng(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        book_lat = place.getLatLng().latitude;
                        book_lng = place.getLatLng().longitude;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                    //returns list of addresses, take first one and send info to result receiver
                    Geocoder geocoder;
                    List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
                    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

                    book_lat = userPref.getFloat(getString(R.string.p_lat),0.0f);
                    book_lng = userPref.getFloat(getString(R.string.p_lng),0.0f);

                    try {
                        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(book_lat, book_lng, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
                    locField.setText(address);

                } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
                    Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(imageReturnedIntent);
                    Toast.makeText(GetDonorAddressActivity.this, "Error: " + status.getStatusMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());
                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // The user canceled the operation.
                }
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

}
```

While testing, I found that:

When a single word (of any length) is entered, it works perfectly.

When I try to type the name of a place that has two words (such as saket c... or sobha i...), it gets cleared as soon as I type the first letter of the second word. However, this does not happen if I enter gibberish (like iojsd z...).

Comment: please share some of your findings while debugging the issue. some pattern or logs that you may have noticed. will help people to solve your problem.

Comment: you may have not enabled the api google cloud settings. Had the same error once, to enable it I had to enter payment details. Since I did not want to do this, I used the OpenStreetMaps API for finding addresses, which is not as good as the google one since you got no autocomplete.

Comment: I have entered payment details. Why is this happening?